# Different shaped UIButtons

Tags: iphone, uibutton

IS it possible to have UIButtons of different shapes or orientation?

e.g. a 45 degree button. Is it possible to rotate a button of the x axis?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could play around with the [transform](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4) property of `UIView`:

```
// convert angle to radians
CGFloat angle = 45 * M_PI / 180;

myButton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle);
```

But that's kinda asking for trouble when it comes to user interaction. It will also transform the button's label, which may be undesirable. Instead, consider using an image for your button; the image can be transparent so as to give the illusion of rotation or a different shape, and there won't be any ill effects.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I asked is because I use an image and it appears to be 45 degrees, but the touch area is the bounding box. I only want the actual image to be the touch area, not the transparent box.

Comment: @alJaree In that case, using the `transform` property might be exactly what you need. Alternatively, you could override the `hitTest:withEvent:` method to change how the touch area is determined: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-BBCCAICB